# How to set up session token between JS and PHP API?

Tags: javascript, php, api, authentication, token

I have designed a simple HTML/CSS and JS/jQuery application, and now it's the moment of authentication integration. On the server side, I have done a REST API which allows clients to get some data. But, now I want to authenticate each request with access and/or session token.

I read many websites to find agreements or advice to establish security between the client (JS) and the REST API (PHP), but unfortunately I found nothing or not interesting.
So I ask you to enlighten me (if you want) to know what to do, what to implement, conventions, etc.

What I read:

[Designing a Secure REST (Web) API without OAuth](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906064244/http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/)

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa)

I cannot post more links according to my reputation...

Just give me advice, ways how to store private token (RSA) or access/session token for API.

Don't hesitate to give your reaction, and tell me if I'm not exact or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a token-based authentication for your REST API. JWTs are the best in this particular case.

Why Use JSON Web Tokens?

1. **Tokens are stateless**. The token is self-contained and contains all the information it needs for authentication. This is great for scalability as it frees your server from having to store session state.
2. **JWTs can be generated from anywhere.** Token generation is decoupled from token verification allowing you the option to handle the signing of tokens on a separate server or even through a different company such us Auth0.
3. **JWTs have fine-grained access control.** Within the token payload you can easily specify user roles and permissions as well as resources that the user can access.

This will be your typical authentication flow process:

1. A user signs up/logs in, during the login process, you generate a JSON web token from the server and return it to the client. Since you are using PHP, you can use this [library](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) for the generation and signing of the token.
2. Store the JWT returned to the client on the browser Web Storage(local/session storage). It can also be stored in a cookie.
3. For subsequent HTTP requests from the client to the server, you send the token via headers/query, then the server validates the token. If it's valid, the user is authenticated otherwise the user is rejected.

[image: Typical authentication flow]

BTW, if you don't want to implement authentication yourself, you can use Auth0, check out [VanillaJS SPA](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs) and PHP [quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/php)

I hope this information helps. Cheers!

Comment: Yes indeed, the information helps! But I want to ask about secret generated by the server. If I understand well, the client sends name and pwd (through HTTPS) and the server generates secret from name and pwd and other. I guess I can generate the sercret like this : hash256(name+pwd) with others hashed parts. It's ok ? What I am doing wrong ? P.S: Your links are really interesting, Thank you.

Comment: I guess you are calling the token "secret". The server generates the token. It's advisable you use a library like I recommended to generate the token. Now, you will need a server secret that the library can use to generate the secure token too.

Answer (score 1):

Authenticating REST API's with JavaScript front-ends is difficult because the JavaScript code is completely readable by anyone visiting the site so storing any kind of login credentials is no good.

With a standard Server to Server set-up simply using basic auth over HTTPS is more than enough but basic auth is no good for JavaScript SPA's as the credentials are in plain view.

For SPA's you need to be looking at JSON WebTokens, as your back end is in PHP you need to be looking at PHP-JWT from firebase. You can get the code here: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt or recommended using composer:

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

The package makes implementing JWT super simple see the docs for a complete code example. Also check out the JWT for a complete break down https://jwt.io/

Comment: I just read this [article](http://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2014/11/27/creating-json-web-token-in-javascript.html) and jwt.io documentation, however I do not understand how to have the secret key on client side. Is generated by the client (I assume not)? How it's generated? I admit this part intrigue me, the key secret is fuzzy to me.

Comment: It's a little complicated to explain in full here. You store the JWT locally in localStorage, the user can exact this but doing so gives the user no extra value. The JWT is encoded (HMAC SHA256 by default) so without knowing the 'secret' another user somehow managed to get hold of JWT from the users localStorage (which I believe there isn't any known attacks yet) couldn't construct and send a false request.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Jwt (https://jwt.io/) is good solution for your question.

On the client side you can store the token on the localStorage or some global variable (for SPA).

You can transfer token on the HTTP header or as request parameter. It works.

Also you can see https://auth0.com/blog/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/